# Get images from /images

Tags: php, sql, path

I have this code to upload data into mysql (including images):

```
<?
require("connect.php");

$gravar_descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
$gravar_observacoes = $_POST['observacoes'];
$gravar_imagem01 = $_FILES['imagem01'];
$gravar_imagem02 = $_FILES['imagem02'];
$gravar_imagem03 = $_FILES['imagem03'];
$gravar_imagem04 = $_FILES['imagem04'];
$gravar_imagem05 = $_FILES['imagem05'];
$gravar_imagem06 = $_FILES['imagem06'];

  if (!empty($gravar_imagem01["name"])) {

  preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $gravar_imagem01["name"], $ext);

$nome_imagem = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];

$caminho_imagem = "../../images/" . $nome_imagem;

  move_uploaded_file($gravar_imagem01["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem);

}


$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tb_carros (id_carro, descricao, observacoes, imagem01, imagem02, imagem03, imagem04, imagem05, imagem06) 
            value ('', '$gravar_descricao', '$gravar_observacoes', '$gravar_imagem01', '$gravar_imagem02', '$gravar_imagem03', '$gravar_imagem04', '$gravar_imagem05', '$gravar_imagem06')";

mysql_query($sqlinsert) or die ("Nao foi possivel salvar os dados");

  echo "Dados inseridos com sucesso";

?>
```

As you can see, I'm working with just the `imagem01` in the code to get the result I want. Then I'll work with the other images.

That code works fine and saves the `image01` in `../../images` as well. But I want to show this image in `carro_admin.php` (the code):

```
<?

require("db/connect.php");

session_start();
     if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
           session_start();
     } else {
           header("location:index.php");   
     }

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_carros";

$limite = mysql_query("$sql");

$dados = array();
while ($sql = mysql_fetch_array($limite) ) {
    $dados[] = $sql;
}
?> 
....
<div class="fotoResumo">
    <img src="../images/<?=$row['imagem01'] ?>" /> <!-- the carro_admin.php is one level up of the insert code -->
</div><!-- END of fotoResumo -->

<div class="dadosResumo">
     Descricao: <?=$row['descricao']?><br /><br />
     Observacoes:   <?=$row['observacoes']?><br /><br />
</div><!-- END of dadosItem -->
```

The data from `descricao` and `observacoes` are loading fine but, the `imagem01` shows a broken image icon. What's wrong?

Comment: Just a small tip you shouldnt use mysql_ functions because they are in the process of being removed and arent really safe. You could use PDO or Mysqli because those are much better.

Comment: what does the source code for the fotoResumo div look like?

Comment: Jimmy, do you mean the PHP code on the page where I put the fotoResumo  div? If yes, its the code above the (....) in the question.

Comment: no i meant the html that your script outputs. it'd be interesting to see the `<img src="` bit.

Comment: This code is fundamentally broken. Using `'$gravar_imagem01'` in your insert query is NOT going to insert **ANY** information about the file. It's going to insert the literal word `Array`. You have absolutely **NO** error handling on the uploaded files, and simply assume all of the uploads succeeded. You're validating **ONE** upload by checking the user-provided filename, which is a horribly insecure thing to do.

Comment: @jimmy the src is in the question: <img src="../images/<?=$row['imagem01'] ?>" /> ... that is the html.

Comment: Ok @MarcB you showed me the problems. Any idea or guide (article) to solve it?

Comment: @AdrianoMachado no that is your script. i'm talking about the html that your script outputs to the browser. "view source" you know.

Comment: @jimmy it's returning an Array just like Marc B said: <img src="../images/Array" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it guys. Here is the final code:

```
<?

            require("connect.php");

            $gravar_carro = $_POST['carro'];
            $gravar_valor = $_POST['valor'];
            $gravar_ano = $_POST['ano'];
            $gravar_km = $_POST['km'];
            $gravar_cor = $_POST['cor'];
            $gravar_portas = $_POST['portas'];
            $gravar_combustivel = $_POST['combustivel'];
            $gravar_cambio = $_POST['cambio'];
            $gravar_final_placa = $_POST['final_placa'];
            $gravar_carroceria = $_POST['carroceria'];
            $gravar_descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
            $gravar_observacoes = $_POST['observacoes'];
            $gravar_imagem01 = $_FILES['imagem01'];
            $gravar_imagem02 = $_FILES['imagem02'];
            $gravar_imagem03 = $_FILES['imagem03'];
            $gravar_imagem04 = $_FILES['imagem04'];
            $gravar_imagem05 = $_FILES['imagem05'];
            $gravar_imagem06 = $_FILES['imagem06'];



                        preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $gravar_imagem01["name"], $ext);
                        preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $gravar_imagem02["name"], $ext);
                        preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $gravar_imagem03["name"], $ext);
                        preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $gravar_imagem04["name"], $ext);
                        preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $gravar_imagem05["name"], $ext);
                        preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $gravar_imagem06["name"], $ext);


                        $nome_imagem01 = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];
                        $nome_imagem02 = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];
                        $nome_imagem03 = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];
                        $nome_imagem04 = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];
                        $nome_imagem05 = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];
                        $nome_imagem06 = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];


                        $caminho_imagem01 = "../../images/" . $nome_imagem01;
                        $caminho_imagem02 = "../../images/" . $nome_imagem02;
                        $caminho_imagem03 = "../../images/" . $nome_imagem03;
                        $caminho_imagem04 = "../../images/" . $nome_imagem04;
                        $caminho_imagem05 = "../../images/" . $nome_imagem05;
                        $caminho_imagem06 = "../../images/" . $nome_imagem06;

                        move_uploaded_file($gravar_imagem01["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem01);
                        move_uploaded_file($gravar_imagem02["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem02);
                        move_uploaded_file($gravar_imagem03["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem03);
                        move_uploaded_file($gravar_imagem04["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem04);
                        move_uploaded_file($gravar_imagem05["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem05);
                        move_uploaded_file($gravar_imagem06["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem06);



                        $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tb_carros (id_carro, carro, valor, ano, km, cor, portas, combustivel, cambio, final_placa, carroceria, descricao, observacoes, imagem01, imagem02, imagem03, imagem04, imagem05, imagem06)
                        value ('', '$gravar_carro', '$gravar_valor', '$gravar_ano', '$gravar_km', '$gravar_cor', '$gravar_portas', '$gravar_combustivel', '$gravar_cambio', '$gravar_final_placa', '$gravar_carroceria', '$gravar_descricao', '$gravar_observacoes', '$nome_imagem01', '$nome_imagem02', '$nome_imagem03', '$nome_imagem04', '$nome_imagem05', '$nome_imagem06')";


                        mysql_query($sqlinsert) or die ("Nao foi possivel salvar os dados");


                        echo "Dados inseridos com sucesso";

            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You're not inserting the name of the image in your database, but the word "Array".**

You're currently inserting `$gravar_imagem01` into `imagem01`, which equals to  `$_FILES['imagem01']` in your actual code.

Insert **`$gravar_imagem01['name']`** in your **`imagem01`** field instead, as you want to retrieve the name of your image to display it later with `<img src="../images/<?=$row['imagem01'] ?>" />`.

*Note : as you can't use `'$gravar_imagem01['name']'` in your SQL query, I suggest you to store it in a temp variable before, then use it on your query.*

Comment: @AdrianoMachado If you want me to clarify something, feel free to ask